# Echo at the end of Bat file not work

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I have 2 batch files and Im trying to use echo at the end of the second file as follow.

1.bat:

```
call 2.bat
```

2.bat:

```
(echo here work)
emcc {with params}
(echo here don't work)
```

but it seems that the echo work only when it in the begining.
I must call it from `2.bat` althought it work if I call it in `1.bat`

Comment: `start "" emcc` as currently the window will wait for emcc to exit, before going to the last echo.

Comment: actually the cmd /c is better for me bc I want to print only when emcc is done so it was your previous solution, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, we start `emcc` which will stop console to wait for completion.

```
@echo off
echo I will tell you when done...
start "" "emcc {with params}"
echo I am done!
pause
```

As per comment, if you want to wait for exit code to be successful, then do this by waiting for completion and testing for exit code.

```
@echo off
echo I will tell you when done...
cmd /c emcc && echo I am done!
pause
```